# jQuery Mobile height issue for iPhone web app, assumes page height of 480 instead of 460

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

jQuery Mobile seems to calculate the page height upon initializing, but since we enable the status bar in our app, JQM assumes we have 480 px available instead of 460 px.

We're building mobile web apps for iPhones.

We're using JQM 1.1.1 and PhoneGap 2.0.

Any idea how to override the JQM setting? We tried manually setting the page height to 460 px ourselves (after JQM defines the page height), but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a JQM issue. We had 'height=device-height' in our viewport meta tag. Removing this solved the problem.

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow. Thanks man -- saved me an hour or so probably.

Comment: argh, I have the same issue, but needed 'height=device-height' to solve this new bug in ios7 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19145211/1061602