# MGWT app showing keypad issue in ios7

Tags: ios7, mgwt

I developed an app using MGWT.It is working fine in ios6. I upgraded to ios7.here I'm facing few problem I have 10 MTextBox widgets, I want to show all in my view.for this i add them to a WidgetList and I added my widgetList to a scroll panel and finally I added my scroll panel to main layout of the view,.till now no problem at all, but when I tapped on the 6,7,8,9,10 th textboxes, the ios keypad is appearing. this appearance of keypad overlapping my 6,7,8,9,10 textboxes. because of this overlapping  these textboxes are not even taking the text input.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. We can resolve the above issue by setting the viewport height to device height, this can be in 2 ways, one is  myapp.gwt.xml configuration and the other is, adding these lines in our onModuleLoad()

1)xml configuration:see this:[viewport height adjustment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949647/webkit-overflow-scrolling-forms-broken-on-ios-7-full-screen-web-app/19405771#19405771)

2)code snippet::

```
MGWTSettings settings =  MGWTSettings.getAppSetting();
ViewPort viewPort = settings.getViewPort();
viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight();
viewPort.setWidthToDeviceWidth();
viewPort.setUserScaleAble(false).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMaximumScale(1.0);
viewPort.setTargetDensity(DENSITY.MEDIUM);
settings.setViewPort(viewPort);
MGWT.applySettings(settings);
```